# Leaving USA with a New Zealand passport being in trouble with the law with and without warrants

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality

Can a dual citizen USA and New Zealand citizen leave USA with a New Zealand passport without worries with a court case (misdemeanor) pending or being on court probation (misdemeanor) and with fines owed to the court also if I have a warrant or without warrants what is likely going to happen ? Will they let me leave because I have documentation showing I'm a New Zealander?

Comment: Confession time: What is your actual situation and problem? Where are you trying to flee to and what are you running away from? Besides that, you are likely about to get even deeper into trouble than you already are, sooner or later.

Comment: Are you asking about what will happen with regard to your pending cases, or just about the laws concerning travel from the US to New Zealand?

Comment: With regard to travel, I doubt you'd have trouble leaving the US, but I'm not certain. You might try at [Travel.SE].  You are probably aware that leaving the US under these circumstances could lead to a situation in which you can't return to the US without a high risk of imprisonment, though. You'll also want to investigate the arrangements that the US and New Zealand have for extradition.

Comment: @phoog not sure OP wants to leave to NZ, thus I had close-voted as unclear.

Comment: @mts there was a comment earlier that made it clear that settling in NZ is the contemplated goal.

Comment: Hire a lawyer in the State where the case is pending.

Comment: Are you under a court order or promise not to leave the country? If not, then technically, I don't think you are breaking any law by leaving. However, if you have promised to appear for the court case at a certain time, you will still need to return to the US to attend at that time.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be in a bad situation and it's good that you are trying to get help. However, strangers on the Internet who are not familiar with your specific situation are not the right people to talk to.

Please try to find someone you trust or go to a local legal clinic or pro-bono service (cheap or free) with all your paperwork.

Most of what you are suggesting sounds like a terrible idea and is likely to get you into even more trouble (at least with the US). But only someone familiar with the rules and your specific situation can help properly.

Comment: True, and +1, but in the other hand fleeing a misdemeanor for a chance at a "clean" life might be the safest alternative.